# how to post score on googleplus iphone using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I did game in iPhone using cocos2d and i want to post score on Google Plus.I searched For this but i didn't get any information.can you provide me some information regarding Google Plus integration in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

```
 There is a Google + API but it is provides read-only access.
link of Google + API:    
https://developers.google.com/+/api/#calls
```